# how do i get count of columns from 3 different but identical table with column values greater than 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 tables that look like this:

```
Table1

ID    x     y      z    
1     0     30     0     
2    60      0     0     
3    10     30     0     
4    30     30    30 



Table2

ID    x       y      z    
1     0       0     50  
2     0      10      0     
3    10      30      0     
4     0       0      0 


Table3

ID     x      y      z    
1     20     30      0     
2      0      0     40     
3      0     30      0     
4     30      0     20
```

I want to be able to query this and return the ID with the number of columns that have more than 0 as their value in that row. So the result would look like this:

```
ID    Count
1      4
2      3
3      5
4      5
```

Comment: What is the difference between the tables? Because from what i see normalisation into one table is the best option it also makes writting a query much more easy

Comment: I want to be able to query this and return the ID with the number of columns that have more than 0 as their value in that row. So the result would look like this:    ID    Count
           1     4
           2     3
           3     5
           4     5

Comment: Agree. Normalise your schema

Comment: there is no diference but the they all take data from different sources

Comment: Have one table with an extra column: source

Comment: "there is no diference but the they all take data from different sources" make two tables  one table with `id`, `source` columns and one table with `id, x, y, z, source_id` columns

Comment: @JayBlanchard atleast duplicate to a MySQL syntax union version.. Topicstarter `[C:\DB\DB1.mdb]` with in the duplicated link isn't valid MySQL syntax so you can't use that in MySQL.. Brackets are SQL Server  (MSSQL) only.. The rest is valid MySQL syntax..

Comment: My bad @RaymondNijland, was doing it from my phone and my fat old fingers chose the wrong one.

Comment: No problem @JayBlanchard those things happen.. i have atleast update mine comment so it contains some explaination about the duplication link.. I geuss the topicstarter should understand those to get a query going..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly, but this is simple and should do what you are asking for.

```
select id, sum(case when x > 0 then 1 else 0 end + case when y > 0 then 1 else 0 end + case when z > 0 then 1 else 0 end) count
from (
select id, x, y, z from table1
union all
select id, x, y, z from table2
union all
select id, x, y, z from table3) tables
group by id;
```

Comment: your answer is good but i think you left out 'GROUP BY id' thanks

Comment: You're right, I forgot the group by clause.  Can you mark the answer as accepted?